# Connecting vb.net SQL Server dataset

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2008

I created a program using VB.net 2008 and SQL Server 2005. And I am using dataset to connect to SQL Server and Crystal Reports getting data from connection to database too.

But I find it difficult and troublesome to reconnect it every time I switch computers. I mean I have to change the dataset's database address to the new computer SQL Server's server name. And so is the same with the Crystal Reports. Just wondering is there any codes or any ways to connect it automatically without reset the connection every time.

The question is kind of confusing but I hope you guys understand what I mean.

Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 1):

If the database is stored locally you can use a name or an address of local computer: `.`, `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. If database is on a network server the addres should be permanent unless you are moving between networks and DNS servers.